# Work around or disable CPU usage limit

Tags: smart-contract, nodeos, cpu

In a private testing environment I've got a single nodeos instance. In case it is an important detail, note that the instance is *not* running the eosio.system contract.

One of my own contracts is resulting in "transaction exceeded the current CPU usage limit imposed on the transaction."

I'd like to disable that error or at least increase the CPU usage limit to the point where it doesn't matter.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4343:

> If you've never modified your max_transaction_cpu_usage and
>   max_block_cpu_usage, it will be the value defined in your genesis
>   (check your genesis via nodeos --print-genesis-json). To check its
>   latest value, you can use cleos get table eosio eosio global but only
>   if you have uploaded eosio.system contract
>
> Two ways for you to modify it:
>
> 1. Use your own defined genesis.json when starting your own chain (this
>      is only possible if you own the chain and you want to restart the
>      whole chain from the beginning)
> 2. Upload eosio.system contract, and then
>      use setparams action

Answer (score 1):

Execution of any action of smart contract maximum transaction is 150ms,You have to execute this action before 150ms.I also tried increasing CPU limit but nothing happen.So we modified smart contract which should execute any action before 150ms

Comment: If what you're trying to do will take a long time inevitably, I would also recommend splitting the work into more transactions so that you can call the action several times and it will process part of what you want it to do each time until there is nothin left and then you can stop calling it.